# how to use javascript variable in struts2 param tag

Tags: javascript, struts2

I want to  use current year value in properties file, it should be send to `<s:text>` tag as a parameter using  `<s:param>` tag with `new Date().getFullYear()` value.

Comment: question is not clear what you trying to achieve here.provide more details

Comment: Have you tried <s:property value="new Date().getFullYear"/> and if so why do you need to store the current year in property file?  Anyways if that gives the expected result you can set it into a parameter and would probably be a lot easier to read in a jsp.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried and the right syntax is:

```
<s:property value="%{new java.util.Date().fullYear}" />
```